# Change Selection in a ListView from Orange to Green

Tags: android, android-listview

How do I do this per selected list item.

I tried adding this to `android:background`

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" 
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@color/android_green" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" 
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@color/black_alpha" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" 
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@color/black_alpha" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/white_alpha" />
</selector>
```

but it does not work, it changes the entire ListView.

---

Still not working, here is what I have so far

::listview_background

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/black_alpha" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/white_alpha" />  
</selector>
```

::My view that is using the above

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/list" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_below="@+id/round"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/listview_background">
</ListView>
```

The problem is that the black_alpha will apply the the entire list, not just the selected list item

Comment: Same solution but with full source coding is provided on this site [http://android-codes-examples.blogspot.com/2011/03/customized-listview-items-selection.html](http://android-codes-examples.blogspot.com/2011/03/customized-listview-items-selection.html) here it is mentioned clearly about where to provide the xml as background in the listview, so that we can easy grap it

Answer (score 21):

Here's a [good article](http://android-journey.blogspot.com/2009/12/android-selectors.html) on how to use selectors with lists.

Instead of setting it to be the `android:background` of the ListView, I believe you want to set `android:listSelector` as shown below:

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/list" 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:divider="@null" 
      android:dividerHeight="0dip"
      android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />
```

Comment: I think it is not working because I am using a @color instead of an @drawable

Comment: This is the "right" solution. The "standard" android backgrounds can be found in the folder android-sdk\platforms\android-14\data\res\drawable-mdpi search after list.

Comment: @jax: YES! I had a selector set like this, but it was painting the whole list. I changed every color to a shape with that color and it worked. However I've seen this problem on 2.2, but not on 2.3 and 4.0, so I guess they corrected this behavior.

Answer (score 8):

Jax, you said that:

> The problem is that the black_alpha will apply the the entire list, not just the selected list item

I had the same problem. After playing around with it for a while, I was able to get it to stop applying the color to the whole list by using a 3x3 png image of the color I wanted instead of applying a color. So for some weird reason if you use a color you get the odd background behavior, when you use a png, it works fine. :S

So that is one way to get around it.

-----Another way----------

I found the best results when I set the listView selector to not have any states like this:

res/drawable/list_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
</selector>
```

Then I take care of all the states in the background of the list item. NOT in the selector. I found I had more control this way.

res/color/list_item_bg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_selected="false"
    android:state_pressed="false" 
    android:drawable="@color/list_item_black_translucent" />
<item android:state_pressed="true" 
    android:drawable="@color/light_green_accent_translucent" />
</selector>
```

Then here is my list item:

res/layout/simple_list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingRight="45dip"
android:paddingBottom="2dip"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
android:background="@color/list_item_bg">
  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/arrow"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dip"
    android:src="@drawable/list_item_arrow" />
 <TextView
android:id="@+id/simple_list_item_label"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:textSize="12sp"
android:textColor="@color/list_label_color"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Just want to add that your "other way" also works great if the list items have a margin, since setting a listSelector on the whole list seems to ignore any item margins. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: but this will always draw the selector in the background, and that's not always desired. you could create an overlay for the whole item, but that's not the best solution...

Answer (score 3):

I was also facing your problem where the color change applies to the whole list.

But now its working for me now:

My main page containing the listview (noticed I did not apply the listselector here):

```
 <ListView 
    android:id="@+id/controlList" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Instead applied the listselector to getView, its like tell **that particular row (convertView)** to use the listselector.xml in drawable foldable when its state changes, e.g. pressed, focused...:

```
@Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder viewHolder;
            if(convertView == null){
                LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = li.inflate(R.layout.control_list, null);
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

                viewHolder.topText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.toptext);
                viewHolder.bottomText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bottomtext);
                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

            }
            else{
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }


                    //each convertView will be assigned the listselector
            convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.listselector);


            viewHolder.topText.setText(testSchemes[position]);

            //viewHolder.vText.setText(testDetails[position]);
            return convertView;
        }
```

And finally my listselector.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="false"
        android:state_selected="false"
        android:drawable="@color/lightgreen" />

    <!-- Even though these two point to the same resource, have two states so the drawable will invalidate itself when coming out of pressed state. -->
    <item android:state_pressed="true" 

        android:drawable="@color/darkgreen" />

    <item android:state_selected="true" android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@color/orange" />



</selector>
```

This is what the above code does:
All entries when first loaded are lightgreen.
Scrolling up and down using cursor highlights the selected entry orange.
Pressing a row turns it to darkgreen.

Answer (score 2):

As bigstones mentioned in a comment, a working solution is using a shape instead of a color (I was also getting the whole list highlighted). Here is a complete solution:

add these 2 attributes to the listview:

```
android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
android:listSelector="@drawable/my_list_selector"
```

add my_list_selector.xml to drawable folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle"> 
    <solid android:color="#77526F35"/>
</shape>
```

Now the list items should show a semitransparent green overlay on pressed state.

Comment: Nice +1 this was the simplest fix for me. Fixed my 2.3 issue. Can just apply the selector on the listview - happy times

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and then I just needed a simple line in my item view xml.

```
    android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
```

Check this post: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15741857/androids-selector-for-selected-item-does-not-work/18037464#18037464) could help