# setSelector causes undesired behaviour when using a ListActivity

Tags: android, listactivity

I'm trying to set the color of an item in a list when it is selected. i.e., my list is normally grey, but I want the item selected by the user to glow yellow when pressed.

In the `onCreate` method, I tried to use `getListView().setSelector(R.xml.list_pressed)`

However this demonstrates the odd behaviour of changing the background color of the entire list instead of individual elements! I'm stumped as to why that occurs.

The `ListActivity` is part of a `TabActivity`, if that makes a difference.

Thanks.

Edit: This is list_pressed.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_enabled="false"
        android:drawable="@color/darkgray" />
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@color/yellow" />
    <item
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@color/darkgray" />
</selector>
```

Comment: Have you checked out the answers to this question?    
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170531/change-selection-in-a-listview-from-orange-to-green

Comment: Can you quote the contents of R.xml.list_pressed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. It turns out I had set the background color for each item in a xml file, and this isn't overridden by the selector. Replacing the background with list_pressed as the drawable fixed the issue. I'm surprised I didn't notice this earlier. >_<

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a state for `android:state_pressed="false"`

You may have made a mistake at `android:state_enabled="false"`, you're xml should read like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@color/darkgray" />
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@color/yellow" />
</selector>
```