# Android's selector for selected item does not work

Tags: android, listview, css-selectors

I have a listview, where I want to highlight selected items in a custom way.  I'm setting every item properties in the adapter's `getView` method, including `itemView.setSelected(true)`.

The main layout defines the listview in the following way:

```
<ListView
android:id="@+id/list"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />
```

(Playing with choice mode does not help either).

The **list_selector** is an almost empty stub:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

I don't need specific styles for listview as a whole, so I'd leave a default one, but according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10501314/1102014), we need a selector for a listview for item selector to work. Anyway, without the **list_selector** the problem remains.

The listview item layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:background="@drawable/listitem_background"
    android:orientation="vertical">
```

and it references the following **listitem_background** selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@android:color/white" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

The problem is, that selected items do not have white background.

If I change `android:state_selected="true"` selector in the **listitem_background** to, for example, `android:state_pressed="true"`, then the selector starts to work, that is item background becomes white if an item is touched.

So, I suppose, there is an error either in the selectors, or in the way how I select items.

I can write a workaround by setting background from Java or utilizing checkable states, but I want to understand and fix current problem with selectors. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12):

What about adding this line in your item view?

```
android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
```

For instance:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewListRowOption"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Then the selector looks something like this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime">

<item android:drawable="@drawable/list_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/list_selected" android:state_activated="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/list_default"/>

</selector>
```

And the list view:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listViewMainFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_item_selector"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice">
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This is just for API 11+ :(

Comment: My listitem turns Holo Blue this way, not the color in my selector.

Comment: Why can't we set the same selector to the layout also ?

Comment: @Joan P.S 
this is hiding then contents of list item too (e.g text and icon)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one to change the selected list item.Put it inside the list view.

```
if (currentSelectedView != null && currentSelectedView != v) {
                unhighlightCurrentRow(currentSelectedView);
            }

            currentSelectedView = v;
            highlightCurrentRow(currentSelectedView);



private void unhighlightCurrentRow(View rowView) {
        rowView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);//to set a color for un-seclected row
    }

    private void highlightCurrentRow(View rowView) {
        rowView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selector_img);//to set a color for seclected row
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is just one of the unwanted workarounds I have mentioned in the question (Java coding).