# Selector in Custom View With 9 Patch Image Background

Tags: android, android-listview, selector, android-selector

I have problem with implementing selector in custom view. I have searched it for the last 1 hour but I could not find the solution. I have custom view with imageview, some textviews and nine patch background but the problem is when it's on pressed state, the color of selector doesn't cover the image view.

[image]

For the implementation, I'm using background selector for the layout and I just change the 9 patch image on pressed and un-pressed state, then disable default selector in listview.

Do you have any better solution? I see in google play, the blue selector covers all of the views and that is what I want.

For the xml,

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/touch_selector"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="16dp" >

    <ImageView />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView />

        <TextView />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And for the touch selector

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/card_background_pressed" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/card_background_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/card_background_white" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false"/>

</selector>
```

where card_background is 9 patch image.

EDIT :

This is the example from google play,

[image: Google play]

Comment: `the color of selector doesn't cover the image view` do you mean that the green selector should cover the whole list item, or that the image itself should get a background green?

Comment: Yeah, the green selector should cover the whole list item. It looks like green selector on top of the item with 50% opacity. The great example is like in google play list item.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the google play list item example, please, because I really fail to see what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm really sorry for my bad English. This is the example from google play. Google play has great selector so the touch feedback can cover the imageview. http://oi41.tinypic.com/jziqud.jpg

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2170554/247095

Comment: I don't think so. it's just about selector in listview..

Answer (score 2):

The accepted is not correct.
It's possible to use a nine-path in the selector, you just need to use the <nine-patch>. Something like this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true">
        <nine-patch 
            android:src="@drawable/marker"/>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#000000" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Comment: you got the question a bit wrong but you just answer my question kkk